# Permission LIst of applications (Android)

Tags: android, user-permissions, android-permissions

I want a list of permission of the application installed in android , but as seen by other applications which offer privacy advisor , they have explained or grouped the permission.

Also seen when installing a new application on the device.

1. How can i get grouped permission list ?
2. Any specific way to classify them ?
3. Is there a particular way to get the groups or permission group ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System permissions are listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) and permission groups [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html). All you need is to use PackageManager to get apps' permissions and then keep doing what you want to do.

Comment: Is there a classification , which group consists of which permissions ?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html